# Set a due date column using a trigger

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I'm working on a Sqlite database where a table has both a `initial_date` column and a `due_date` one. I'd like to automatically set the latter's value using a trigger every time the former one's value is changed, but something doesn't works.

Here's a simplified versione of the table DDL

```
CREATE TABLE timetable (
    id           INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,

    initial_date DATETIME,
    due_date     DATETIME
);
```

As you can see, the two `DATETIME` columns allow `NULL` value; this is because in the real table I'd like to insert rows without setting the `initial_date` and update those rows later for setting the `initial_date`.

This is the trigger I added

```
CREATE TRIGGER [timetable-due-date] AFTER UPDATE ON timetable
BEGIN
    UPDATE timetable
        SET due_date = DATE( NEW.initial_date, '+ 10 days' )
        WHERE id = NEW.id
            AND NEW.initial_date IS NOT NULL;
END;
```

but it doesn't fires. If I execute `UPDATE timetable SET initial_date='2013-10-04' WHERE id=1`, `due_date` keeps the initial `NULL` value.

I also tried using the `CREATE TRIGGER ... AFTER UPDATE OF initial_date ON ...` variant, but without any luck.

I'm surely doing something really stupid here, but I can't figure what.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your date modifier is wrong; there must be no space between the `+` and the number:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "timetable-due-date"
AFTER UPDATE OF initial_date ON timetable
WHEN NEW.initial_date IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE timetable
    SET due_date = DATE(new.initial_date, '+10 days')
    WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

Comment: That's right, I completely miss it. Once fixed that syntax, it worked without any problem. Moreover, the `initial_date IS NOT NULL` check works both in the `WHEN` and the `WHERE` clauses.